# ListView check box does not check upon selection

Tags: java, android

The following code stops working when I add an if else statement. The commented code works when uncommented, but adding the if statement does not show the "Checked" in the listview item. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view,int position,long id){

    //Toast.makeText(this, events[position] + " Alarm Set ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(view!=null){
        Toast.makeText(this, events[position] + "Invalid email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, events[position] +"Please check your email!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Any logcat output? When positing errors where your code crashes make sure to post the output.

Comment: It doesnt crash... it just shows the "Invalid email" toast , but it does not "check" the listView item. :(

Comment: Well all you are checking here is if the View isn't equal to null. If you have populated any sort of view in the listveiw you won't get null. What are you trying to check in the listview itself?

Comment: I am trying to have the "check box" show the check mark when I tap on a listview item. I think I am comparing the wrong data. This works fine by itself "//Toast.makeText(this, events[position] + " Alarm Set ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();" but when I add the if, the check does not work anymore

Comment: Well if you have already populated your view you don't need the if clause? If there is a text value in there then we can check that but you need to be more clear.

Comment: The functionality expected is, to click on a list item, have the item check display and when clicking again, the check mark goes away. Thank you for your patience good Sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96597/discussion-between-jordan-seanor-and-user3078406).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
if(listView.isItemChecked(position)){
 //logic
}else{
 //other logic
}
```

Comment: Note to other users, we discussed this in a CHAT I will post a more in-depth answer shortly!

Comment: Thank you so very much! Amazing!

Comment: Sir, Jordan Seanor can you give me a hand with something? I cant seem to send you a message directly. :)

Comment: Sure man @user3078406  shoot me an email. jordanseanor@gmail.com